# Order in desc after getting result from a nested query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. I get result in order by desc format.
Now I want to display info in that same order format. But I am not able to do that.

```
select *
  from table1  
 where field in (select * 
                   from table2 
                  where StartDate > '2011-11-01' 
                    AND StartDate < '2011-11-30'
               group by field1 
               order by count(field1) desc );
```

The inner query is ordered in descending, but when used with the outer query, the order is lost.

Comment: That query should be returning an error for comparing `table1.field` to all the columns in `table2`...

Comment: Are you sure that is your actual working query? `where field in (select * from` looks strange.

Comment: Yes. But I figured out the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An `in` clause does not preserve ordering, I'm surprised MySQL even allows it like that :)

One solution is to calculate the count in a subquery, and use that to order:

```
select  *
from    table1 t1
join    (
        select  field1
        ,       count(field1) as Field1Count
        from    table2 
        where   StartDate > '2011-11-01' 
                and StartDate < '2011-11-30'
        group by field1 
        ) t2
on      t1.field1 = t2.field1
order by
        t2.Field1Count desc
```